# Jade: multiple nested REST arguments to build image carouel

Tags: pug

I'm trying to build an image carousel where the main images are "small" with each of them linked to "large" versions. My code so far is:

```
mixin carouselImages(title, subtitle, ...imagesLG, ...imagesSM)
p.text-center: small!= title
    .footnote.text-center!= subtitle
.owl-carousel.chocolat-parent(data-chocolat-title=title)
    each img in imagesLG
        a.chocolat-image(href=img)
        each img in imagesSM
            img(src=img)
```

And when I call the mixin I'm using:

```
+carouselImages(
    "Carousel Title",
    "Carousel Subtitle", 
    "http://www.linktosmallimage.com", "http://www.linktoLARGEimage.com",
    "http://www.linktosmallimage.com", "http://www.linktoLARGEimage.com",
    "http://www.linktosmallimage.com", "http://www.linktoLARGEimage.com"
    )
```

The expected output would be that the href links to the large image, the img src points to the small image.

I've tried various indents and nesting, but nothing seems to work and compile.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Changed the mixin to:

```
mixin carouselImages(title, subtitle, ...images)
p.text-center: small!= title
    .footnote.text-center!= subtitle
.owl-carousel.chocolat-parent(data-chocolat-title=title)
    each img in images
        a.chocolat-image(href=img.LG)
            img(src=img.SM)
```

And the mixin call to:

```
+carouselImages(
"Carousel Title",
"Carousel Subtitle", 
{SM: "http://www.linktosmallimage.com", LG: "http://www.linktoLARGEimage.com"},
{SM: "http://www.linktosmallimage.com", LG: "http://www.linktoLARGEimage.com"},
{SM: "http://www.linktosmallimage.com", LG: "http://www.linktoLARGEimage.com"},
)
```

Works perfect now.